# Retrieve Professional Skills from Facebook Graph API

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api-v2.0

Last year, Facebook introduced Professional Skills into your About > Work & Educations > Professional Skills.

I would like to know, if Facebook has API to retrieve that piece of data?

Answer (score 0):

According to the official docs, it's not available...

[Link to the official doc](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user)